# How can I create a Carousel Indicator at the bottom of the Carousel in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Can i see a draft or sample code that has Carousel Indicator in it? I tried searching for it in documentation of Kivy MD and found nothing, I wanna try to add a indicator to see where the current active slide is at. Thank you!

here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv='''
<Start>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.941, 0.886, 0.835, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        # pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}

        Carousel:
            direction: "right"
            Image:
                source: 'images/cacaostart1.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "300dp", "300dp"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}

            Image:
                source: 'Images/cacaostart2.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 300, 300
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}

            Image:
                source: 'Images/cacaostart1.png'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 300, 300
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}

                
    MDLabel:
        text: "Welcome to Cacao Guard"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Start"
        font_size: "18sp"
        font_name: "Raleway-Black.ttf"
        text_color: "white"
        md_bg_color: "#A08264"
        line_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
        on_release: root.go_to_login_screen()

'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class Start(Screen):
    def go_to_login_screen(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"
```

I tried inserting CarouselIndicator but it  didn't work.

Comment: did you mean to set `kv` to be that really long string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to your `Carousel`:

```
    Carousel:
        id: car
```

And use that in a `MDLabel`:

```
MDLabel:
    text: "Carousel Index: " + str(car.index)
    halign: "center"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
```

Comment: Tried this and the carousel doesn't slide anymore, also it adds a string "0" after the text.